# Preview documents listed in custom webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document

I'm new to SharePoint 2013 and have been given a task to preview a document.

The document to preview is not within the search results.

Is this possible to achieve? How do you achieve it? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the document formats u want to preview, but if you have office web apps installed it should preview the documents from ms office and pdf files.

Screenshot of my sharepoint online environment:
[image: Office web apps]

Refrences:

How to install and configure office web apps:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn455088(v=office.15).aspx

This is as far as I know the best practice for previewing documents.